# Unable to Update to Android Studio 3.5.1 From 3.5.0

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 3.5.0 which was the latest version until yesterday. Today I got a new update 3.5.1 and I tried to update android studio. But unfortunately I am getting this error whenever I try to update the Android Studio.

```
Some conflicts were found in the installation area.

Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied. Press `Cancel` to exit.

File: Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib
Action: Validate
Problem: Modified
Solution: NONE
```

I think this is somewhat related `JRE` as it shows some issue in file `Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib` But not sure what to do to solve this.

[image: n]

Comment: Did you try to move that file and install it?

Comment: @pasanbuddhika Did that. Not working.

Comment: Can I know your java version and the result for `md5 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib`

Comment: @pasanbuddhika The result is: `MD5 (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib) = 4cdb20c37ebac9b7b03b1e04a45caf66` and Java version is `java version "1.8.0_144"`